# Creating UDF with VSTO in Excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vsto

I know how I can do this for the simple case as details here:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140715145511/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/Denis/archive/2007/01/03/102623.aspx)

But what I'm trying to do is when my category is selected in Excel I want to be able to dynamically populate the function list at run-time.

As is, it's populated using all public function in the category DLL. Is there some way of hooking into the event that populates this list and telling it what to use? Or maybe injecting some code into the DLL dynamically, in this case I could insert a bunch of public functions into the DLL at run time and so have what I want in the function list

Answer (score 0):

With ExcelDna - http://www.codeplex.com/exceldna -
you can explicitly register the functions at runtime. However, I don't think it is easy to know when the function list is displayed, so you might have to have a menu items or something that fills the list.