# How to add code to a DLL at run time

Tags: c#, .net, dll

Let's say in the constructor of my .NET class I want to write code that will actually add methods to my class dynamically. So now when I reflect over my class I will see the methods where as when I first built the project the methods didn't exist

How can I achieve this?

I've been looking up CodeDom but it's all a bit confusing

Comment: Are you trying to develop classes/code outside of the IDE?

Answer (score 3):

Once you've loaded the assembly, you cannot change it.  You can use Reflection.Emit or CodeDom to dynamically compile a new assembly, with a class that is just like yours + extra methods, but it will not change the existing (at least existing at runtime) class.  Potentially, you could load your class in a separate AppDomain, create a new class that was a "copy" of it with the extras, then load that assembly in your main AppDomain (and unload the one where you loaded your original class).  You're still creating a new class, not adding to an existing one, but the effect would be similar.

You can use code injection to insert code before the class is loaded, however.  There are some code injection frameworks for .NET that would help with this...  but that is different than your specific question.

Answer (score 1):

you have to either use Reflection.Emit or Mono.Cecil or PostSharp.

All of them are easy to learn...

Answer (score 0):

I.... can't imagine why you would want to do this.

Could you explain why you would want to?

Instead, try having different concrete implementations of the same interface, or abstract class if you're sharing most of the code.

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885682/creating-udf-with-vsto-in-excel

Read the last sentence of the post

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without learning anything extra using [CInject](http://codeinject.codeplex.com) (open source at Codeplex).  Write the code to be injected in C# or VB.NET and then get it processed through CInject to be added into a managed assembly.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @reed-copsey using appdomain domcomplie functions. You can make a plugin class that inherits a plugin base class, you can add all the Classes you want. When it compiles in the appdomain it will even be able to give you coding errors that were injected into that class. It then wont compile that specfic class. At least you will know the code has a problem.